# Filter mysql array output against another table field vaule

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array I fetch from a table named `MYLISTS`.

Say the MYLISTS outputs an array: `(1,XYZ,XX) (2,ABC,XX) (3,123,XX)`.

I want to filter that output by checking to see if `XYZ`, `ABC` or `123` exists in another table called `MYNAMES`. If there is not value in `MYNAMES` for the NAME `123`.

I would then want to only have the output values of `(1,XYZ,XX) (2,ABC,XX)`

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: The most efficient would be to modify your original database query, so what does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like below:

```
SELECT A.* FROM MYLISTS A INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM MYNAMES
) B ON A.name = B.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `MYLISTS` 
WHERE name IN (SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM `MYNAMES`)
```

here `name` is a `column` in both tables `MYLISTS` and `MYNAMES` containing the values like `XYZ`, `ABC` or `123`